# FileNotFoundException - Array loops over deleted files

Tags: java, arrays, file, filenotfoundexception

I have several files inside a folder. What I am trying to do is to load the content of each file, then delete them and wait for new files to be created in the folder. My code is the following:

```
while(true){

        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        if(files != null){
            Arrays.sort(//sorting...);

            //Here we manage each single file, from data-load until the deletion
            for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
                loadTweets(files[i].getName());
                //TODO manageStatuses
                files[i].delete();
                statusList.clear();
            }

        }

    }
```

Unfortunately after the first **correct** deletion, I get this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

on the deleted file.
What is wrong with my code?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You might want to do like `if(files[i].exists())` to confirm that there is such a file before you try to do things with it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried only to print the file name on each itineration to see if what's inside the files array is correct?

Comment: The problem is in your `loadTweets` method, because the `delete()` method does not throw this exception. The FileNotFoundException javadoc clearly says: "an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname has failed." You're loading the tweets by file name, so this is presumably where it happens. (Also did you try getting the file *path* instead of name?)

Comment: Thats because you are looping twice while(true) and for all files. Why you need while(true)?

Comment: following up on @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas comment try files[i].getAbsolutePath();

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro at which point should I try that method?

Comment: @Santosh - Presumably on the second trip through the while-loop, the `listFiles()` method would return an empty array, not the same files, since the for-loop deleted the files.

Comment: @sirdan comment out all the lines inside your for but the delete one and use System.out.println(files[i].getAbsolutePath()); if the problem is on the second itineration of the for you might see some errors but probably is the second itineration of the while.

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro you were right, the second itineration throws the Exception. Still don't understand why. Any clue?

Comment: @sirdan the second itineration of the for cycle?

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro yes

Comment: solved it: I had to pass `files[i].getAbsolutePath();` to loadTweets. Thanks everybody.